# NumberFormatException: Invalid int

Tags: android, sqlite

Good day I'm having a problem inserting a data because of this.
Here's my code:

addItem.java

```
public class AddItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


SQLiteLocalDatabase sqLiteLocalDatabase;

    EditText editTextFullName;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    EditText editTextEmailAdd;
    EditText editTextPassword;
    EditText editTextIDNO;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnUpdate;
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);

    sqLiteLocalDatabase = new SQLiteLocalDatabase(AddItemsActivity.this);

    //CALL FUNCTION
    setUpWidgets();
}

public void setUpWidgets(){
    editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFullName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Location);
    editTextEmailAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailAddress);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextIDNO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddContacts);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonAddContacts:
            //IF result == -1
            long result = sqLiteLocalDatabase.insert(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)),
                                        getValue(editTextFullName),
                                        getValue(editTextAddress),
                                        getValue(editTextEmailAdd),
                                        getValue(editTextPassword)
                                      );
            if(result == -1){
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Sucess Id:"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.buttonUpdate:

            long update = sqLiteLocalDatabase.update(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)),
                    getValue(editTextFullName),
                    getValue(editTextAddress),
                    getValue(editTextEmailAdd),
                    getValue(editTextPassword)
            );
            if(update == 0){
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error Updating",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
                if(update == -1){
                    Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Updating",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error All data updated Id:"+update,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.buttonSearch:
            break;

        case R.id.buttonDelete:

            long delete = sqLiteLocalDatabase.delete(Integer.parseInt(getValue(editTextIDNO)));
            if(delete == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Error Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(AddItemsActivity.this, "Success Delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;


    }
}

public String getValue(EditText editText){
    return  editText.getText().toString().trim();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sqLiteLocalDatabase.setUpDb();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sqLiteLocalDatabase.closeTransactionDb();
}
}
```

For the database

```
public class SQLiteLocalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private static final String DB_NAME = "project.db";
private static final int VERSION = 1;


public static final String DB_TABLE = " user ";
public static final String ID = " _id ";
public static final String FULL_NAME = " fullname ";
public static final String LOCATION = " location ";
public static final String EMAIL_ADD = " email ";
public static final String PASSWORD = " password ";


public SQLiteLocalDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String queryTable = " CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ FULL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + EMAIL_ADD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL" + " ) ";

    db.execSQL(queryTable);
}

public void setUpDb(){
    //TO OPEN DATABASE - RE-WRITABLE
    sqLiteDatabase  = getWritableDatabase();

}

public void closeTransactionDb(){
    //CLOSE DB IF OPEN
    if(sqLiteDatabase != null){
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
}

//INSERT DATA
public long insert(int id,String fullname, String location,String email,String password){

    //CONTENT VALUE contains name-value-pairs
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    if(id != -1) {
        values.put(ID,id);
        values.put(FULL_NAME, fullname);
        values.put(LOCATION, location);
        values.put(EMAIL_ADD, email);
        values.put(PASSWORD, password);
    }
    //Object Table, column, values
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_NAME, null, values);


}

//UPDATE
public long update(int id, String fullname,String location,String email, String password){
    //CONTENT VALUE contains name-value-pairs
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FULL_NAME,fullname);
    values.put(LOCATION,location);
    values.put(EMAIL_ADD,email);
    values.put(PASSWORD,password);

    //WHERE
    String where = ID + "="+id;

    //Object Table, values, destination-id
    return sqLiteDatabase.update(DB_NAME, values, where, null);
}

//DELETE
//
public long delete(int id){
    //WHERE
    String where = ID + "="+id;

    //Object Table, values, destination-id
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(DB_NAME, where, null);
}

public Cursor getAllRecords(){

    String queryDB = "SELECT * FROM "+DB_TABLE;

    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryDB,null);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

additem_xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:inputType="text"**
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_icon"
    android:hint="ID no, you can leave it!"
    android:textColorHint="@color/textPrimaryColor"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextID"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

THIS is the error message I always get. I think the EditText convert to Integer is the problem here. **I even changed the inputType ="number/text".**

```
NumberFormatException: Invalid int:
```

Answer (score 0):

`editText.toString()` is not the string entered into the `EditText`. You need to use [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()):

```
//CREATE METHOD for EditText
public String getValue(EditText editText){
    return editText.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: I got java null exception and pointing to this method. And also to my 

long insert = sqLiteDatabase.insert(..........); :(

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                             at project.app.elective.ccs.mobileappproject.activities.AddItemsActivity.getValue(AddItemsActivity.java:117)
                                                                                             at project.app.elective.ccs.mobileappproject.activities.AddItemsActivity.onClick(AddItemsActivity.java:65)

Comment: My question wasn't *where* is returning null, it is *what* is null - is `editText` null? Is `editText.getText()` null? Is `sqLiteDatabase` null? These are all potential issues which have nothing to do with your original question ('why don't you get the entered in text?') that would still cause your app to fail.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was going to school. In my sqLiteDatabase  = ID  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FULL_NAME TEXT NOT NULL, LOCATION TEXT NOT NULL, EMAIL_ADD TEXT NOT NULL, PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL . The Id is optional in the EditText, if the user don't enter a value the ID in my database will generate it (autoincrement). I'm following this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umUO6jRKgz8&index=26&list=PLgjt1h_kabFebUn1anGYZ6_Tfkw64Ww12

Comment: To check if they are NULL, I set a value for each EditText by .setText(""); for the Id = -1, still I get an error.